# How to add or insert ' (single quotes) for every string in a list in which strings are separated by commas using Java

Tags: java, string, list

I have a list as below

```
[url1,url2,url3,url4]
```

This list will be based on multiple selection from drop down list of HTML. So list size i.e., list elements change dynamically. My problem is I am unable to get the logic for getting single quotes to the strings.
I want the above string list to be displayed as

```
'url1','url2','url3','url4'
```

That is single quotes (`'`) for each string and commas (`,`) should not be eliminated. Please help me how to achieve this using Java.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Not able to get the logic for keeping quotes.But able to remove the [ and ] using replace()

Comment: Are we talking about a `List<String>` containing your "url" variables (in that case they would be displayed between double-quotes) or a `String` representing your list as "[url1, url2, etc]"?

Comment: You can take each element from list and put it in between single quotes and add it back..Try this in code and let us know if you have any problem..

Comment: One option is to split the string on comma, then append single quote to each word and then append all words back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Iterate the list (for/while).
2. For each element in the list append `<element-of-list>`. Hint: use `append()` on `StringBuilder`.
3. Truncate/substring the list to remove the last element added. Hint: use substring on `String` class.

Comment: StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder(); Now b.append("''")will not append ' at begining and ' at ending of string right??

Answer (score 46):

for list  you can convert this by Java 8

```
 list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

Answer (score 22):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
...
...
String arr[] = new String[4];
arr[0] = "my";
arr[1] = "name";
arr[2] = "is";
arr[3] = "baybora";

String join = "'" + StringUtils.join(arr,"','") + "'";
```

Result:

```
'my','name','is','baybora'
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use Java 8 utility class `java.util.StringJoiner`.

This class specifically introduced to format list of string values.

For example:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("','", "'", "'");
        joiner.add("url1");
        joiner.add("url2");
        joiner.add("url3");
        joiner.add("url4");
        System.out.println(joiner);
```

**Output**

```
'url1','url2','url3','url4'
```

Note that, in constructor of `StringJoiner`,

```
StringJoiner(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix)
```

we are passing single quote as prefix and suffix to satisfy your specific requirement.

Answer (score 15):

Using Java 8 Streams:

```java
String[] array = {"url1", "url2", "url3", "url4"}

Stream.of(array).collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Most fast and efficient way to do this

Ex.

```
ArrayList<String> a=[url1,url2,url3,url4];

String s  ="'"+a.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "").replace(" ","").replace(",","','")+"'";
```

Answer (score 5):

Have one Util.java file or if you already have all common util stuff then just add these static methods

> for single quote

```
public static String singleQuote(String str) {
        return (str != null ? "'" + str + "'" : null);
}
```

> for double quotes

```
public static String doubleQuotes(String str) {
        return (str != null ? "\"" + str + "\"" : null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have your elements in an array, you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {"url1","url2","url3","url4"};

        ArrayList<String> sl = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            sl.add("'" + s[i] + "'"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    String[] str = {"url1","url2","url3","url4"};
    ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String k:str)
        strList.add("'" +k+ "'");
    System.out.println("Printing the list");
    for(String k:strList)
        System.out.println(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use Java8 built-in features for String concatenation and third-party libraries for wrapping each string in quotes.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StringJoinerTest {
    @Test
    public void testStringJoiner() {

        //init test data
        String s1 = "team1";
        String s2 = "team2";
        List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>(2);
        teams.add(s1);
        teams.add(s2);

        //configure StringJoiner
        //when some values will be added to joiner it will return string started with prefix "(" an finished with suffix ")"
        //between prefix and suffix values will be separated with delimiter ", "
        StringJoiner teamNames = new StringJoiner(", ", "(", ")");
        //if nothing has been added to the joiner it will return  this value ('')
        teamNames.setEmptyValue("(\'\')");

        //fill joiner with data
        for (String currentString : teams) {
            //if you need to wrap each string in single quotes you can do this via org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils#wrap
            // or org.springframework.util.StringUtils#quote
            teamNames.add(StringUtils.quote(currentString));
        }

        System.out.println(teamNames.toString());
    }
}
```