# JAVA Adding a Single quote in String based on the delimeter

Tags: java

`String values = "12,34,56,47,56,34,56,78,90,12,12,34,45";`

how to add Single quotes before the delimeter in above string.

Expected output:
`'12','34','56','47','56','34','56','78','90','12','12','34','45'`

I have done this by `awk` command `awk '{print "\x27"$0}'  | awk '{print $0"\x27"}'` 
Sorry if it's too basic, iam an UNIX Engineer migrating my code to JAVA.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465323/how-to-append-single-quotes-into-both-side-of-stringbuilder-object-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate and co-related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400583/how-to-add-or-insert-single-quotes-for-every-string-in-a-list-in-which-strin/39785566

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative to the replace you could do it like this:

```
String values = "12,34,56,47,56,34,56,78,90,12,12,34,45";
String output = values.replaceAll("(\\w+)","'$1'");
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: not work when id are like  (2664da92-bc0f-611e5dc3-559e10bc2e51,e46f08d5-a4a1-5674-6a98'-'559e101e9b78)

Answer (score 8):

You can do,

```
values = "'" + values.replace(",", "','") + "'";
```

This will replace each `,` with a `','`. Also put one `'` at the start and end of string.

Comment: @Suresh, did this because compiler will take care of putting the StringBuilder...;)

Comment: Ahh.. time to cry, dear compiler :D